# Save an array in a cell in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I want to write an array of numbers like [1,2,3,4] into a cell of csv file.

My csv file should look like

```
 Title        array 

'file1' ,  '[1,2,3,4]'

'file2'  , '[3,4,5,6]'

'file3'  , '[6,8,2,9]'
```

I want to do this since i want to save this csv file in mysql database.
So that i can retreive the data from the database later.

Can anyone explain How to write this in python.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, for your testdata you can do it in this way

```
import csv
with open('example.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',escapechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    csvwriter.writerow(['file1' , '[1,2,3,4]'])
    csvwriter.writerow(['file2' , '[3,4,5,6]'])
    csvwriter.writerow(['file3' , '[6,8,2,9]'])
```

With this code I could create an csv-file, which you described.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
sample=[[1,2,3,4],[3,4,5,6],[6,8,2,9]]
fileName=['file1','file2','file3']
df=pd.Series(sample)
df = df.to_frame()
df.rename(columns = {0:'Array'}, inplace = True)
df['Title']=fileName
cols = ['Title','Array']
df = df[cols]
df.to_csv('file1.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

Not quite sure I fully understand the question. The CSV file will read comma separated values as individual cells by default, so likely your output will be like: 'file1' ,  '[1,  2,  3,  4]'
which will result in 5 columns, unless you change the delimited or the way you parse it.

But to get the output like you suggested the simple program like the following will do:

```
f = open('out.csv', 'w+')
f.write("Title, array\n")
f.write("{0}, {1}".format(file_name, array_def))
f.close()
```

where for example

```
file_name = 'file1'
array_def = [1,2,3,4]
```

Hope that helps.